# Почему код не срабатывает, хотя он написан с соблюдением разных стандартов (ECMAScript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Почему код не срабатывает, хотя он написан с соблюдением разных стандартов (ECMAScript) ?
Вот код:

```js
$('.tab').click( function () {
    $('.tab').css({
        'color': 'gray',
        'border': '1px solid #ececec'
    });
    $(this).css({
        'color': '#000',
        'border': '1px solid orange'
    })
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">1</div>
<div class="tab">2</div>
<div class="tab">3</div>
<div class="tab">4</div>
<div class="tab">5</div>
<div class="tab">6</div>
```

А этот не срабатывает ...

```js
$('.tab').click( ()=>{
    $('.tab').css({
        'color': 'gray',
        'border': '1px solid #ececec'
    });
    $(this).css({
        'color': '#000',
        'border': '1px solid orange'
    })
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">1</div>
<div class="tab">2</div>
<div class="tab">3</div>
<div class="tab">4</div>
<div class="tab">5</div>
<div class="tab">6</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что стрелочная функция не имеет своего `this`-а.

```
// 1.
$('.tab').click( ()=>{
    ...
    $(this).css({ // !!! this здесь тот же, что и в строчке 1.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 4):

Главная особенность стрелочных функций не их краткость, а то что у них нет контекста, то есть `this` не установлен на `$('.tab')`:

```js
$('.tab').click( function(){console.log(this);} ); // Html элемент
$('.tab').click( () => {console.log(this);} ); // Window
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">Click</div>
```